# Change Value of String

Tags: java, string, metadata, media

I have a simple media player and in one of the classes I need to retrieve the metadata of the media. Thus far, I have successfully extracted the metadata, however when I attempt to use the values, the Strings returned are blank.

```
String album = "", artist = "", title = "", year = "";
...
public void addListItems(final Pane layout, final Stage stage, final Scene scene) {

if (list != null) {
    for (final String s : list) {
    final String[] sList = s.split("\\\\");
    Media media;
    try {
        media = new Media(new File(s).toURI().toURL().toString());
        media.getMetadata().addListener(new MapChangeListener<String, Object>() {
        public void onChanged(Change<? extends String, ? extends Object> arg0) {
            handleMetadata(arg0.getKey(), arg0.getValueAdded());
        }
        });
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    lab = new Button(album + sList[sList.length-1]);
    layout.getChildren().add(lab);
    lab.setPrefWidth(scene.getWidth());
    lab.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
    lab.setStyle("-fx-border-color: black");
    lab.setStyle("-fx-backgound-color: lightgray");
    lab.setTooltip(new Tooltip(lab.getText()));
    lab.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        public void handle(MouseEvent arg0) {
        try {
            AudioBitsMediaPlayer.mediaPlayer = AudioBitsMediaPlayer.buildMediaPlayer(s, AudioBitsMediaPlayer.status, AudioBitsMediaPlayer.timeStatus);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        AudioBitsMediaPlayer.currentDir = new File(new File(s).getParentFile().getAbsolutePath());
        AudioBitsMediaPlayer.status.setText("Audio File");
        stage.close();
        }
    });
    scene.heightProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> arg0, Number arg1, Number arg2) {
        lab.setPrefWidth(scene.getWidth());
        layout.setPrefHeight(scene.getHeight());
        }
    });
    }
}       
}
...
public void handleMetadata(String key, Object value) {
    if (key.equals("album")) {
        album = value.toString(); //Here album returns as value.toString() correctly
    } else if (key.equals("artist")) {
        artist = value.toString();
    } else if (key.equals("title")) {
        title = value.toString();
    } else if (key.equals("year")) {
        year = value.toString();
    }
    }
```

I have done research on this topic, but the results I viewed did not help my circumstance. I greatly appreciate any assistance.

Comment: May be artist = (String) value; works??

Comment: Thanks, but that's the equivalent of value.toString(). It makes no difference

Comment: Can you try to do debug value ? it contains something?

Comment: In the HandleMetadata method, I debugged with System.out.println(). It contained a value, however, when I attempt to use this value in the addListItems method, it shows as "".

Comment: So in handleMetadata(String key, Object value) you get "" as value but in onChanged is another?

Comment: Class `Change` is made by yourself?

Comment: In onChanged i receive "" and in handleMetadata() the value is returned as "Youth", the correct album name.

Comment: I did not create class Change. It is default.

Comment: Can you link the documentation? I can't find it. But if in handleMetadata you get the right value what is your problem?

Comment: My issue is that I need to include the album name in the text of the button. I recieve the album name from the handleMetadata() method, that much works, however when I attempt to include the album variable in my button name it returns as a blank string. I do not understand how, after setting the value, the String can still be blank.

Comment: your problem is when you are splitting your main string

Comment: Here is the documentation http://books.google.com/books?id=Wp9Xrm1ujncC&pg=PA352&lpg=PA352&dq

Comment: I just omitted the line where i split the string, there was no change aside from it showing the entire directory of the media.

Comment: Since you've declared String s as final you can't change it's value by s.split(); right? I don't exactly get it in which line of code you get blank string value?

Answer (score 0):

Please try to do this:

```
artist = (String) value; 
title  = (String) value;
year   = (String) value;
```

Comment: I just tried it after you asked. It made no difference.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: but I think that I did give a possible solution, but it doesn't works @KevinPanko

Answer (score 0):

- You should probably use `String.valueOf(value)` because that will
  work even if the value is Integer or anything else.
- For `value.toString()`  you will need to check if value is null else it will throw     `NullPointerException`
- Same can happen when u try to cast  `(String) value;`

Comment: Thank you for the response, however it still returned "".